# Force developer to use a particular constructor

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following class

```
  public class UIControl
  {
    public string FName{ get; set; }
    public HtmlInputCheckBox SelectCheckBox { get; set; }
    public bool OverrideSelect { get; set; }

    //Want to throw an ApplicationExceptioh if developer uses this constructor and passes
    //chkSelect = null
    public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect)
    {
      this.FName= sFieldName;
      this.SelectCheckBox = chkSelect;
    }

    public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect, bool overrideSelect)
      : this(sFieldName, chkSelect)
    {
      OverrideSelect = overrideSelect;
    }
  }
```

I want to make sure that the developer uses the first constructor only when chkSelect is not null.

I want to do a:

```
throw new ApplicationException("Dev is using the incorrect constructor");
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a private constructor thus:

```
public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect) 
    : this(sFieldName, chkSelect, false, false)
{      
}    

public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect, 
     bool overrideSelect)      
    : this(sFieldName, chkSelect, overrideSelect, true)    
{      
}  

private UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect, 
   bool overrideSelect, bool allowOverride)      
{      
    if ((!allowOverride) && (chkSelect == null)) 
         throw new ArgumentException(...);
    this.FName= sFieldName;      
    this.SelectCheckBox = chkSelect;    
    OverrideSelect = overrideSelect;    
}
```

There are lots of variants, but as a general rule, have less specific constructors calling more specific ones.  For example, the following would also work in your case:

```
public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect)    
    : this(sFieldName, chkSelect, false)
{      
   if (chkSelect == null) throw ...
}    

public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect, 
     bool overrideSelect)    
{      
    this.FName= sFieldName;      
    this.SelectCheckBox = chkSelect;    
    this.OverrideSelect = overrideSelect;    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Whats hard?

```
public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect)
{
    if (chkSelect == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Dev is using the incorrect constructor");
    }

    this.FName= sFieldName;
    this.SelectCheckBox = chkSelect;
}
```

Comment: The 2nd constructor calls the 1st one, so if i check for chkSelect == null then it will throw an exception even when they have the OverrideSelect set

Comment: I love how three people post the exact same code in less than 30 seconds... ;)

Comment: Then you will need to modify the second constructor so that it doesn't use the first constructor.   The constructor #2 has different rules than #1, and therefore cannot use #1.

Comment: I posted a separate updated answer that shows how to separate the two constructors so that one allows a potentially null chkSelect, while the other does not.

Comment: Should be an ArgumentException, not an ApplicationException

Comment: OP wrote that he wanted ApplicationException, so I stuck with that.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
//Want to throw an ApplicationExceptioh if developer uses this constructor and passes
//chkSelect = null
public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect)
{
  if (chkSelect == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentException("chkSelect cannot be null when using this constructor");
  }
  this.FName= sFieldName;
  this.SelectCheckBox = chkSelect;
}
```

Comment: I love how three people post the exact same code in less than 30 seconds... ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's a better practice (or more common practice, since C# doesn't have default parameters until 4.0) to have less specific constructors use the more specific constructors, and not vice versa. You can then utilize a private constructor with a nullable bool. If you are able to rewrite them, try the following:

```
public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect)
  : this(sFieldName, chkSelect, null)
{
}

public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect, bool overrideSelect)
  : this(sFieldName, chkSelect, overrideSelect)
{
}

UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect, bool? overrideSelect)
{
  if (!overrideSelect.HasValue && chkSelect == null)
  {
      throw new ArgumentException("chkSelect");
  }
  FName = sFieldName;
  SelectCheckBox = chkSelect;
  OverrideSelect = overrideSelect ?? false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not like this?

```
public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect)
{
    if (chkSelect == null) 
    { 
        throw new ApplicationException("Dev is using the incorrect constructor"); 
    }
    this.FName= sFieldName;
    this.SelectCheckBox = chkSelect;
}
```

However, it is probably a **bad idea** to do this via a runtime error. A better idea is to use an overload that doesn't take the `chkSelect` argument at all, or to make `chkSelect` non-nullable.

**EDIT:** I noticed now that the second selector calls the first one, but the only thing the second one does is change the value of the `OverrideSelect` field. Why not just have one constructor, and set that field? Or why have that field at all? A couple of alternatives:

```
// This is now the ONLY constructor you need
public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect)
{
    OverrideSelect = (chkSelect == null);
    this.FName= sFieldName;
    this.SelectCheckBox = chkSelect;
}


// You could solve it differently by replacing OverrideSelect with this property:
public readonly bool isChkSelectNull {
    get {
        return (this.chkSelect == null);
    }
}

public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect)
{
    this.FName= sFieldName;
    this.SelectCheckBox = chkSelect;
}
```

Comment: How can you make chkSelect non-nullable (except by redefining it as a struct type)??

Comment: This might be quite a lot of work if you're only going to use it this once, but it looks promising and reusable: http://blog.johannesh.dk/2008/10/how-to-make-non-nullable-type-wrapper.html

Answer (score 0):

Get Spec# or Contracts from .Net 4.0 and make the parameter non-nullable

Answer (score 0):

Based on updated info from the OP:

```
public class UIControl
{
    //Want to throw an ApplicationException if developer uses this constructor and passes
    //chkSelect = null
    public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect)
    {
      if (chkSelect == null)
      {
        throw new ApplicationException("Dev is using the incorrect constructor");
      }
      this.FName= sFieldName;
      this.SelectCheckBox = chkSelect;
    }

    public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect, bool overrideSelect)
    {
      this.FName= sFieldName;
      this.SelectCheckBox = chkSelect;  // note: chkSelect MAY be null here.

      OverrideSelect = overrideSelect;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of throwing Exceptions for programmer issues.  Instead of throwing the Exception, how about Debug.Assert().

Answer (score 0):

Why should you throw an exception if chkSelect is null?

Anyways, to answer what you asked (not what necessarily what you really need), I think you might be doing it backwards. Have the 2 parameter version call the 3 parameter version.

```
//Want to throw an ApplicationExceptioh if developer uses this constructor and passes
//chkSelect = null
public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect)
  : this(sFieldName, chkSelect, chkSelect==null)
{
  if(chkSelect==null) throw new ArgumentNullException("chkSelect");
}

public UIControl(string sFieldName, HtmlInputCheckBox chkSelect, bool overrideSelect)    
{
  this.FName= sFieldName;
  this.SelectCheckBox = chkSelect;
  OverrideSelect = overrideSelect;
}
```

Comment: thank's for catching my thow   (hah, get it? :P ) Sorry I didn't load up the IDE to type it. In any case, chkSelect==null very much is what I intended to write. Why do you believe this won't work? Can you please teach me?

Comment: my mistake.  chkSelect == null in the parameter is a valid boolean.  I first read it as an attempt at a parameter with a default value.